# Aggregate two arrays where both elements not null in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

## Problem

I'd like to get two equally long arrays where both don't contain `null` elements.

## Approach

I can successfully return two arrays, but they contain `null` values. When I exclude `null` values they're of course not equally long.

```
aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: '$row'
  }, {
    $match: {
      $or: [{
        'row.identifier': 'fah'
      }, {
        'row.identifier': 'agr'
      }]
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: '$row.identifier',
      rows: {
        $push: '$row.value'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

### Result

```
[[5, null, 64, 34, 1], [53, 31, null, null, 7]]
```

`null` values still present.

### Wanted result:

```
[[5, 1], [53, 7]]
```

`null` values and values at the same index are removed.

---

## 1. Update

Here are two example documents as requested:

```
[{ // 1st
  row: [{
    value: 53,
    identifier: 'agj'
  }, {
    value: 51,
    identifier: 'hrw'
  }, {
    value: null,
    identifier: 'rgs'
  }]
}, { // 2nd
  row: [{
    value: null,
    identifier: 'agj'
  }, {
    value: 72,
    identifier: 'hrw'
  }, {
    value: 11,
    identifier: 'rgs'
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Can you show some sample documents by way of editing your question?

Comment: @chridam I've added two example documents.

Comment: @Julian your example document and your example query do not match. Could you update your question to have matching examples? What is the significance of `identifier`?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way of doing this filtering in mongodb, I'm not that familiar with it. But in javascript you could write a filter function like the following:

```
var notNullFilter = function(inputs){
    var outputs = [];
    for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
        outputs.push([]);
    }
    for (var k=0; k<inputs[0].length; k++){
        var isNull = false;
        for (var j=0; j<inputs.length; j++){
            if (inputs[k][j] == null){
                isNull = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isNull){
            for (var l=0; l<inputs.length; l++){
                outputs[l].push(inputs[l][k]);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

If you were using a library like lodash this would be much easier but this function should work.